# can nginx set variable from file?

Tags: nginx

```
server {
    set $serverNames /www/test.txt;
    server_name $serverNames;
    ...
```

I want to know if I can read the content from the text and assign it to the variable.I tried the above code and it didn't work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't think you can "read" files into variables by default.

There are third party modules which may read a value of a location
(which itself could refer to files) into a variable, for example [nginx-eval-module](https://github.com/vkholodkov/nginx-eval-module).

But for your use case I think is overkill (and you will depend on a third party module).

What NGINX can do is *include* code snippets in your configuration.

For example, you can do:

```
# nginx configuration
server {
    include /www/test.txt
    ...
}

# /www/test.txt
server_name
    example.com
    example.net
    ...
;
```

and so on.

If `test.txt` is an automatically generated file, it should be pretty easy to
modify the generation script to include `server_name` at the beginning and `;` at the end.

If it's modified manually, well then it's a no brainer.

Comment: yes, test.txt is an automatically generated file.It seems to be useful, I will try it, thank you for your help.

Comment: I wanted to read the content of a file (access token) and add it as header when proxying to the actual endpoint, would that be possible with nginx?